# In Firebird How to create a two dimensional char array domain

Tags: firebird

How do I create a two dimensional char array domain
eg: value

```
['ABC-12121212','1']
['ABC-12323233','2']
```

and and what is the insert/select/update statement if i use this domain in a table field or procedure input.

Is it `CREATE DOMAIN TESTARRAY AS CHAR(14) [500:2];`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend to avoid arrays in Firebird. They are largely a holdover from pre-SQL features of InterBase, and are barely usable from the SQL language.

However, for the syntax of declaring an array domain, see the [documentation on domains](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-domn):

> ```
> CREATE DOMAIN name [AS] <datatype>
>   [DEFAULT {<literal> | NULL | <context_var>}]
>   [NOT NULL] [CHECK (<dom_condition>)]
>   [COLLATE collation_name]
>
> <datatype> ::=
>     {SMALLINT | INTEGER | BIGINT} [<array_dim>]
>   | {FLOAT | DOUBLE PRECISION} [<array_dim>]
>   | {DATE | TIME | TIMESTAMP} [<array_dim>]
>   | {DECIMAL | NUMERIC} [(precision [, scale])] [<array_dim>]
>   | {{CHAR | CHARACTER} [VARYING] | VARCHAR} [(size)]
>     [<array_dim>] [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
>   | {NCHAR | NATIONAL {CHARACTER | CHAR}} [VARYING]
>     [(size)] [<array_dim>]
>   | BLOB [SUB_TYPE {subtype_num | subtype_name}]
>     [SEGMENT SIZE seglen] [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
>   | BLOB [(seglen [, subtype_num])]
>
> <array_dim> ::= '[' [m:]n [,[m:]n ...] ']'
> ```

The `m:n` refers to the lower and upper bounds of the array, so `500:2` would mean an array with a lower bound of 500 and an upper bound of 2, which of course doesn't make sense. If you want multi-dimensional arrays, then separate bounds by a comma (`,`). See also the documentation on the [array type](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-datatypes-array).

In other words, use:

```sql
CREATE DOMAIN TESTARRAY AS CHAR(14) [500,2];
```